# Is there a URL forwarding to the App Store review creator in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios11

In iOS 10, I was able to forward directly from my app to its App Store ratings page by using the following link:

> http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=***app_id_here***&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8

However, in iOS 11 with its all-new App Store where the review page doesn't exist any longer, this seems to be broken now.

Does anyone know an alternative url that opens up the review creator page directly? Or does Apple want us to stop using such links?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a name after the app parameter of your url (here I use 'itunes-u') :

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-u/id\(appID)?ls=1&mt=8&action=write-review
```

Also note that the scheme seems to be working properly so you could instead call :

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-u/id\(appID)?ls=1&mt=8&action=write-review
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is implement the `SKStore​Review​Controller` for IOS 10.3 and higher.

It's super simple,

```
import StoreKit
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

> It turns out that the system will automatically limit the display of the dialog to 3 times over a 365-day period, so there’s no logic required to check this.
>
> There is however a recommendation that you show the prompts at ‘logical points’ when it is clear the user has made some sort of engagement within the app.
>
> The guides also say you should allow a week or two between repeated displays of the prompt so users don’t feel like they’re being pestered(this will require some thoughtfulness and implementation on your part).

- Jordan Holland

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, they did not ask how to request a review from the user

Comment: While that's true, their end goal is to provide an easy way for the user to review their application

Comment: Don’t know that, perhaps they want to simply view other users’ reviews

Comment: @Will what you say is true in the case of a popup, but if we have a button somewhere in the app to redirect the user to the review page we would like a more suitable method for this.

Answer (score 0):

First, according to apple guidelines you shouldn't do this,

but you can just add to itunes link of your game &action=write-review and just open this link.